# If Akrodha is considered a virtue, then why most sages and Devtas do not possess it?

Tags: vedas, shiva, rishi, devatas

Akrodha is a virtue according to Hinduism and Krodha is consider a tamas quality. Absence of anger (akrodha) means being calm even when insulted, rebuked or despite great provocation. Akrodha does not mean absence of causes of anger, it means not getting angry and keeping an even, calm temper despite the circumstances.

I haven't read a lot of mythology or either of the vedas, puranas but from whatever I have read and heard all my life, almost every rishi had huge anger issues, like Parshuram, Indra, Kali aur rudra roop of Shiva and almost any of the rishi munis of that time.

If someone is being called a god, like literally the most supreme being of cosmos, the infinite , one beyond time and space, one would not expect him to have anger issues which are of tamas quality.

Comment: there is no universally good or bad thing, it depends on situation. If someone is beating a poor cow with iron rod, should you be angry at that guy or not ?

Comment: @mar Each and every situation can be dealt without anger. The ones including necessary violence too. You don't need anger to get rid of adharma.

Comment: Rajas and Tamas are important qualities. There cannot be any creation without Rajas. There cannot be any destruction without tamas. Destruction not only means end-of-yuga destruction, but even causing the death of someone is an example of destruction. Brahman, taking up the quality of tamas, causes destruction. Brahman, taking up the quality of rajas, causes creation. In all cases, brahman itself is not affected.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth - that is not true. Sri Ram he is called Jitha-Krodha = Won-Anger. Note that he is not called Hantha-Krodham = Killed-Anger. It means that when he wants, anger will come to him, and when he doesn't want, anger will leave him. He used this anger to kill Ravan only when Ravan started attacking Hanuman. Until that time, he did not use anger in the war.